# No parameter reassign in function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reduce

i have a javascript object like this:

```
cardControlEditFormData= {
 cardBlocked: true,
 posForeignLimit: 1000,
 posGrLimit: 1010,
 cnpGrLimit: 1010,
 posGrPreviousLimit: 0,
 posForeignPreviousLimit: 0
}
```

So i have to create a new object with a specific condition. My code is here:

```
export const prepareCardControlFormData = cardControlEditFormData => Object.keys(cardControlEditFormData).reduce((cardControlData, key) => {
  if (key === 'cardBlocked') {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
    cardControlData.cardBlocked = cardControlEditFormData.cardBlocked !== EMPTY_STRING;
  } else if (key === 'posGrLimit') {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign,max-len
    cardControlData.posGrLimit = cardControlEditFormData.posGrLimit ? (cardControlEditFormData.posGrPreviousLimit || cardControlEditFormData.posGrLimit) : CARD_CONTROL_ZERO_VALUE;
  } else if (key === 'posForeignLimit') {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign,max-len
    cardControlData.posForeignLimit = cardControlEditFormData.posForeignLimit ? (cardControlEditFormData.posForeignPreviousLimit || cardControlEditFormData.posForeignLimit) : CARD_CONTROL_ZERO_VALUE;
  } else if (key === 'cnpGrLimit') {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign,max-len
    cardControlData.cnpGrLimit = cardControlEditFormData.cnpGrLimit ? (cardControlEditFormData.cnpPreviousGrLimit || cardControlEditFormData.cnpGrLimit) : CARD_CONTROL_ZERO_VALUE;
  }
  return cardControlData;
}, {})
```

;

But the eslint throw me an exception that i should not reassign parameter, how to write this in a more quality based way without this exception

Comment: I think it must be complaining about other code, I don't see any parameter reassignment happening in that code.

Answer (score 0):

cardControlData is a parameter for reduce() function and you are assigning values to its properties which might be causing eslint to give error. According to eslint docs, if you have the following setting it also gives error.

"eslint no-param-reassign: ["error", { "props": true }]"

Changing props to false will prevent eslint from giving error at assignments to properties.

Check props section for more details.
https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-param-reassign#options

Comment: i've read this but i dont understand what should i do..that why i ask